# How or is it possible to store an array of integers into a dictionary in C#? i.e. is <Integer, int[]> possible?

Tags: c#, arrays, syntax

I'm new to C# and I'm just writing a quick/small scale app for personal use. I would like to have a Hash table that associates enum values to an array containing integers i.e. int [] format. Is this possible without resorting to using an ArrayList?

I played with the syntax and I am having no luck. I basically want `Dictionary<Integer, int[]>`

EDIT:

I'm writing a pattern matching algorithm and there are three different types represented by an enum. I am keeping track of integer values in an array of size 6 to determine a prediction.

The simplification of the problem is that there is a list of integers being built up, and it would be greatly beneficial if I could predict the next part of a sequence before it arrives.

It's a very simple algorithm, and doesn't involve anything complex other than a few math tricks like gcd, etc.

Btw, thank you for the help! –

Comment: I want something along the lines of Dictionary<Integer, int[]> ...

Comment: My initial post was truncated.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve? You have described your problem with the specific (strange) implentation you have in mind, being new in C#, people with more knowledge in C# can suggest better solutions for what your real problem is.

Comment: lol, I feel dumb now =( SOrry for wasting your guys' time.

I was jumping the gun and didn't give VS enough time to remove the red squiggly lines for Dictionary<int, int[]> ... but it actually does work. 

I'm not use to VS.

Comment: @JrTp: just as a hint: you can edit your question - no need to add comments :)

Comment: I'm writing a pattern matching algorithm and there three different types represented by an enum. I am keeping track of integer values in an array of size 6 to determine a prediction.

Comment: It's a very simple algorithm, and doesn't involve anything complex other than a few math tricks like gcd, etc.

Answer (score 6):

This is perfectly valid:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();
dict.Add(1, new int[] {1, 2, 3});
```

So the answer would be yes, you can do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Dictionary<int, int[]>` or `Dictionary<int, List<int>>`

Comment: @Uwe: an edit should be valid and compilable (aka making the answer better, not worse) :)

Comment: @Andreas. So I should have left the formatting as it was, because the content was wrong? (Just asking).

Comment: @Uwe: you did not do an explicit format-edit... you added some code, so you should be sure that that code is valid!

Comment: @Andreas - NO! I did not add _any_ code. I added the code-formatting single backtick-quotes. Nothing more.

Comment: @Uwe: oh ... yes ... i forgot to click `view source` ... sorry!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is possible. Example:

```
Dictionary<int, int[]> items = new Dictionary<int, int[]>();

// add an item using a literal array:
items.Add(42, new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 });

// create an array and add:
int[] values = new int[3];
values[0] = 1;
values[1] = 2;
values[2] = 3;
items.Add(4, values);

// get one item:
int[] values = items[42];
```

Answer (score 2):

Example for enum:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value2,
    Value3
}

...

var dictionary = new Dictionary<MyEnum, int[]>();

dictionary[MyEnum.Value1] = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
dictionary[MyEnum.Value3] = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };
dictionary[MyEnum.Value3] = new int[] { 7, 8, 9 };
```

Usage:

```
int i = dictionary[MyEnum.Value1][1]; // i == 2
```